# Is jstl / jsp as secure as exposing endpoint for forms?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jsp, jstl

I've some functonality that inserts a record into a database - called "insert"

I want to expose this functionality to front end.

As I see it I have two options :

1. Use Spring to expose "insert" as a rest endpoint that accepts URL parameters which will contain the data to be inserted.
   Only problem with this approach is that to secure the endpoint I will need to add Spring security or https. By secure I want to reduce risk of malicious user writing script which invokes endpoint multiple times polluting the DB.
2. Use jstl or plain jsp's to create the form and save it. Advantage of this approach is that not exposing an endpoint ? My experience of using jstl is limited but it appears discovering of where the form is being submitted to is more difficult to discover, also it does not use an endpoint so has advantage of being secure out of box ?

I understand exposing an endpoint and using jQuery/AngularJS to invoke endpoint is probably more modern approach but is it as secure as plain jstl or jsp's ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference. At end of the day you have some funcionality which is reachable via HTTP(S). If you want to restrict the usage, you need some kind of security to prevent this.

Wheter you are coding your frontend in JSP or JavaScript only makes a differende in **how** you establish the required security.

Comment: ok, but if view the source of a page can easily any REST endpoints that page is invoking, also the parameters that being sent to the service are present. If however using JSP then just the "form" attribute is present, which makes it more difficult to invoke the form from a malicious source (as cannot just invoke the form in same way as REST endpoint) ?

Comment: I think you are missing the point. If you have POST REST service, it expects form data. Whether this is sent by a real HTML form generated in a JSP, or some javacript code does not matter. After all JSP is (a not ideal) possibility to implementing a REST API.

Comment: but if using jsp form then do not need to expose an endpoint to capture the form data ?

Comment: So the data of the jsp generated form doesn't get sent anywhere when you hit the submit button?

Comment: I agree it does also get sent to server. I'm just making argument that it is more difficult to discover the data type(json fields etc) the server accepts when submitting the form if using jsp. But if exposing a REST endpoint it is very plain to see what data is being sent to server in order to invoke endpoint. Although, could possibly view the network traffic for jsp form just as easily...